# Connecting several points as a route on Google-maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a JSONarray full of coordinates like that [[lat, long],[lat,long]...] and i want to draw a line on Googlemaps-fragment which is following the route defined by the coordinates.

I just did some research, but i only found solutions using one start and one endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions):

```
PolylineOptions poliLine = new PolylineOptions()
                    .width(10)
                    .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .zIndex(1);
poliLine.add(startPoint.getCoordinates());
for (MyPoint midPoint : points) {
    poliLine.add(midPoint.getCoordinates());
}
poliLine.add(endPoint.getCoordinates());
route = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(poliLine);


class MyPoint {

    public LatLng coordinates;

    public MyPoint(LatLng coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public LatLng getCoordinates();
}
```

In your case, if the coordinates have an order, your `coordinates.get(0)` should be your **startPoint**, `coordinates.get(coordinates.size() - 1)` your **endPoint** and the rest should be **midPoints**.